# How do I prevent matplotlib.pyplot from only showing the sections of the graph where data exists?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, graph

Im trying to show my graph from an entire range(10) on the y axis however the lowest y value is 4 and the highest is 7. How do I make it show the y axis for all points in the range not just the ones where there is a value?

My script is:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import datetime as dt

#X axis data
dates = ['03/04/2017', '04/04/2017', '05/04/2017', '06/04/2017', '07/04/2017', '08/04/2017', '09/04/2017',
         '10/04/2017', '11/04/2017', '12/04/2017', '13/04/2017', '14/04/2017', '15/04/2017', '16/04/2017']

#Y axis data
occurence_number = [7,5,4,6,7,6,6,4,5,7,7,6,7,7]

#formatting the date information
x = [dt.datetime.strptime(d, '%d/%m/%Y').date() for d in dates]
y = occurence_number

#labeling the x and y axis
plt.xlabel('Date')
plt.ylabel('Instances of Behavior')

#here I tried to set the yticks in an attempt to show them all
plt.yticks(range(10))

#formating y axis values for matplotlib
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%d/%m/%Y'))
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.DayLocator())

plt.plot(x,y)
plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
plt.show()
```

I have tried to use:

```
plt.set_autocale_on(False)
```

That causes an error:

```
"'module' object has no attribute 'set_autocale_on'"
```

The other things I have found I don't understand how to implement. The graph currently shows the correct values but I would like to "Zoom" out so that it still shows the y labels from 0-->4 and 7-->10 where there are no values.

Comment: `plt.gca().set_ylim(0, 10)` or `plt.ylim(0, 10)`

Comment: This works great!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the issue using the answer provide by @Paul.

```
plt.gca().set_ylim(0,10)
```